# Getting ValidationFailureSemanticException on 'INSERT OVEWRITE'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a `DataFrame` and registering that DataFrame as `temp` view using `df.createOrReplaceTempView('mytable')`. After that I try to write the content from `'mytable'` into Hive table(It has partition) using the following query

```
insert overwrite table
  myhivedb.myhivetable
partition(testdate) // ( 1) : Note here : I have a partition named 'testdate'
select
  Field1, 
  Field2,
  ...
  TestDate //(2) : Note here : I have a field named 'TestDate' ; Both (1) & (2) have the same name
from
  mytable
```

when I execute this query, I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table$ValidationFailureSemanticException: Partition spec
{testdate=, TestDate=2013-01-01}
```

Looks like I am getting this error because of the same field names ; ie `testdate`(the partition in Hive) & `TestDate` (The field in temp table 'mytable')

Whereas if my partition name `testdate` is different from the fieldname(ie `TestDate`), the query executes successuflly. Example...

```
insert overwrite table
  myhivedb.myhivetable
partition(my_partition)  //Note here the partition name is not 'testdate'
select
  Field1, 
  Field2,
  ...
  TestDate 
from
  mytable
```

My guess is it looks like a Bug in Spark...but would like to have second opinion...Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you are right that the issue is due to duplicate names. Can you try your query with this setting. sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true") . If this solves your issue. I will post a detailed answer.

Comment: @dheee tried it ; not working ; `spark.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")`, `spark` is of type `SparkSession`

Comment: Can you post sample data set of 'mytable'. Sample data will help in resolving the issue.

Comment: What is the **exact** definition of the partition? Does it contain **2** fields?

Answer (score 0):

@DuduMarkovitz @dhee ; apologies for being too late for the response. I am finally able to resolve the issue. Earlier I was creating the table using cameCase(in the CREATE statement) which seems to be the reason for the Exception. Now i have created the table using the DDL where field names are in lower case. This has resolved my issue